# How to encrypt a value while typing in an input field using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I need to encrypt the value that is entered in a field while typing itself using jQuery.

Is that possible?

Comment: Any form that takes a cc number should be using https

Comment: @Dagon you are right about the cc number thing but this question could easily instead be about modifying a field value while it is being edited in another way.. Nothing suggests its about cc numbers?

Comment: Please read this [helpful article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question on Stack Overflow

Comment: @ChristopherKarlsson the question originally specifically asked about credit cards - it has been edited to remove those details

Comment: @Dagon I see, I didn't know that. Well, as previously said you are right about using HTTPS for important things like that.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using the fields onchange event.

```
jQuery('#myField').on('change', function() {});
```

Comment: where is the encryption?

Comment: There are any number of means to encrypt the value I provided an example for how to access the event of of the fields value being changed OP would then need to encrypt the value of the field inside that function. OP asks if it is possible to encrypt the value on the fly. It is, with this function.

Answer (score 0):

Things you are going to need to consider:

1. How am I going to encrypt the text.
2. Do I need to decrypt the text afterwards to read it elsewhere, or am I just doing a comparison (like a password).

For encrypting I suggest [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/). I have used this before and has a number of methods for encryption.

If you are just saving the data without having to decrypt, you'll want to use a [Hash](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#Hashers).

If you are wanting to decrypt the data afterwards to read the original, you'll want to use a [Cipher](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#Ciphers).

Once you've decided upon your set-up, you're going to need to write some code. Christopher Karlsson's method is the basic start, however you'll need to consider the fact that "encrypting as you type" means that your previously entered characters will get encrypted multiple times and the final product won't be a true representation of the encryption of the whole word.

For example if I want to type `foo` and the letter f gets converted to a `p` for example, when I enter the `o` it will then try and encrypt `po` which isn't what you want.

So we're going to need some place to record our original input, in a hidden field I suggest.

Another problem is that encrypted values tend have a lot more characters than you've entered, so we've got to come up with a generous way of dealing with this too otherwise it's going to cause the person entering the text a headache. I would suggest doing something with the focus and blur listener to hide/show the encryption when we get/lose focus

so lets put that all together:

```js
$('input').on('change blur', function() {
  var strName = $(this).prop('name');
  var strEncrypted = '';
  var objOriginal = $('#' + strName + 'Original');
  var strVal = objOriginal.val();
  switch(strName) {
    case 'Hash':
      strEncrypted = CryptoJS.MD5(strVal)
      break;
    case 'Cipher':
      strEncrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(strVal, "Secret Passphrase");
      $('#DeCipher').text(CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(strEncrypted, "Secret Passphrase").toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
      break;
  }
  $(this).val(strEncrypted);
});

$('input').on('keyup focus', function(e) {
  var intKey = e.keyCode;
  $(this).val($(this).val()); // Hack to set the cursor at the end
  var strName = $(this).prop('name');
  var objOriginal = $('#' + strName + 'Original');
  var blnIsChar = ((intKey > 47 && intKey < 91) || (intKey > 95 && inKey < 112) || (intKey > 185 && inKey < 193) || (intKey > 218 && inKey < 223)) // Create boolean for key pressed in an input character
  if (intKey == 8) { // If we pressed backspace
    var strVal = objOriginal.val()
    if ($(this).val().length) { //if we have some characters
      strVal = strVal.slice(0, $(this).val().length); // remove number of characters
    } else {
      strVal = '';
    }
    objOriginal.val(strVal);
  } else if (blnIsChar) {
    var strLetter = $(this).val().slice(-1)
    var strVal = objOriginal.val() + strLetter;
    var strNew = '';
    for (i = 0; i < objOriginal.val().length; i++) { 
      strNew += '●'
    }
    objOriginal.val(strVal);
    $(this).val(strNew + strLetter);
  } else if (e.type == 'focus') {
    var strNew = '';
    for (i = 0; i < objOriginal.val().length; i++) { 
      strNew += '●'
    }
    $(this).val(strNew);
  }
});
```

```css
label {
  width:60px;  
  display:inline-block;
}
#DeCipher {
  font-weight:bold;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/md5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="HashOriginal" name="HashOriginal" />
<input type="hidden" id="CipherOriginal" name="CipherOriginal" />
<p><label for="Hash">Hasher:</label><input type="text" id="Hash" name="Hash" /></p>
<p><label for="Cipher">Cipher:</label><input type="text" id="Cipher" name="Cipher" /></p>
<p>Decipher: <span id="DeCipher"></span></p>
```